# Data driven coded ui test runs fine for first few records but later fails

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I have develop the data driven framework in coded Ui for desktop application ,here test runs fine for first few records but later fails.Individually each iteration is running fine.
But when I added all rows in CSV file,it runs fine for first two run but later on it started a giving an error for each iteration.
For Test method I also set the time out infinite even then it getting fail.
Please suggest what else i should try ..

Regards,
Vikram

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include the error message(s). Please also read [mcve] and the other [help] pages.

Comment: Vikram, Can you provide the error message?